# NodeJS Memcached - Use multiple servers

Tags: node.js, memcached

How can i add multiple memcache server in nodejs?

Like i do in php:

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$memcache->addServer('memcache_host', 11211);
$memcache->addServer('memcache_host2', 11211);
```

Thanks
Radu

Comment: what library are you using?

Comment: @raffian - the latest, i've set memcached: "" in package.json

Comment: there's lots of memcache libraries for node, which one?

Comment: @raffian i've instaled like: npm install memcached ... how can see what type?

Comment: That library seems to be https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached.  The documentation on github explains how to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The library installed when you `npm install memcached` seems to be [node-memcached](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached).

Adding multiple memcached servers is explained in the documentation, specifically [here](https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached#server-locations).

Answer (score 1):

3rd-Eden's node-memcached (https://github.com/3rd-Eden/node-memcached) which you appear to have installed supports multiple servers in its constructor which can accept (among others) an array of strings formatted as "host:port". As is always good advice, "Read The Fascinating Manual".